# initializing static ArrayList field using anonymous class including a block initializer

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

I was playing javaDeathmatch game and encountered a question I couldn't answer. Can you help me?

```
public class DeathMatch {
    private static final List<String> NAMES = new ArrayList<>() {{
        add("John");
        System.out.println(NAMES);
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Nothing in particular
    }
}
```

In this case when we run the JVM, the class will be loaded and first of all its static member 'NAMES' is created and initialized.The ArrayList is also initialized through an anonymous class including a block initializer.
But the problem is we add "John" to 'this' reference and print NAMES and thus it shows null.
The code will run correctly if we make changes this way:

```
System.out.println(this);
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(NAMES);
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: As-is, the code does not compile. You cannot use type-inference with annonymous inner classes. Why exactly do you `extend` from `ArrayList`? This is not a static initializer.

Comment: why not? Actually the code is compiled with no error

Comment: It just has a logical error

Comment: Huh... indeed. It compiles with Java 10, but not with Java 8...

Comment: @Turing85 Makes sense really. The compiler does have enough information to infer the generic type parameter. Seems like a deficiency in Java 8 more than anything.

Comment: @Michael question is... [why does Java 8 refuse to compile it?](https://ideone.com/vy4PhD)

Comment: @Turing85 See [item 3 in JEP 213](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213). As I said, it's just a deficiency in Java 8 which was later fixed.

Comment: If you mean <> the diamond operation yeah it was later fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use "double brace" initialization, you are creating an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` with the outer braces, and the inner pair of braces represents the instance initializer, where you are calling `add` and printing out `NAMES`.  But at the point where you're constructing the `ArrayList`, the `ArrayList` hasn't finished being constructed yet, and it has not been assignd to `NAMES` yet.  The variable `NAMES` still has its default value `null`.

While the syntax may look pretty, it's usually not worth it to create an anonymous subclass just for the sake of easy-on-the-eyes initialization.

Instead, if this must be done statically, then move the initialization of the contents of the list to a static initializer block, so that `NAMES` is already initialized when referenced.

```
private static final List<String> NAMES = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    NAMES.add("John");
    System.out.println(NAMES);
}
```

Comment: "the syntax may look pretty" You think? I think the syntax is incredibly ugly.

Comment: Nice explanation really!

Comment: Another question I have, if we want to use instance initializer here but don't want to extend from Arraylist how can we perform it? what is the syntax of that?
I mean we need one pair of braces for opening anonymous class and another one for instance initializer and that will be the same as above

Answer (score 1):

```
new ArrayList<>() {{
    add("John");
    System.out.println(NAMES);
}};
```

Can essentially be thought of as

```
new MyList();
```

where `MyList` is defined as:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<String> {
    public MyList() {
        super();
        add("John");
        System.out.println(NAMES);
    }
}
```

The order of events goes:

1. Call the constructor
2. Assign the object which is returned by the constructor to the static field named 'NAMES'

So because `System.out.println` happens *within the constructor*, calling it with `NAMES` means the assignment hasn't happened yet and doesn't work, but calling it with `this` is valid.

---

You should prefer one of the following (depending on Java version and the number of elements):

```
private static final List<String> NAMES = Arrays.asList("John");
private static final List<String> NAMES = List.of("John");
private static final List<String> NAMES = Collections.singletonList("John");
```

followed by a static block for the printing:

```
static {
    System.out.println(NAMES);
}
```

Comment: My question is we call to print NAMES after adding it a member so why do you think " calling it with NAMES means the assignment hasn't happened yet and doesn't work, but calling it with this is valid."

Comment: I really can't get it straight

Comment: NAMES only gets assigned after the constructor has finished. You are dereferencing NAMES **in the constructor** (**before** it has finished) so it is still null. NAMES is only assigned (**not null**) after the constructor has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that initialization is not yet completed for the `List` `NAMES` so you are getting `null` for `NAMES` but getting `[John]` while using `this` keyword, if you print that in `main`, it will producing output as desired.